# Can I trigger an event in XAML when a control is less than a certain height?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a grid with two rows, filled with an image and a label.  The label has a locked size, while the image above shrinks with the grid.  When the image becomes so small that it is not really visible, say < 30 pixels high, I want to set its visibility to collapsed, which I think should cause the label to move to the centre of the grid.

It would be nice if this was achieved purely in XAML with some sort of trigger looking for the height to be < x.

Is this possible? If not, what would be the most elegant solution in c# to check on the height of the image?

Comment: Can you not bind the visibility to the grid height using a custom converter?

Comment: I'll google custom converter and let you know. Cheers

Comment: @DanWheeler The converter thing should work, but bind to the Grid's `ActualHeight`, not `Height`. `Height` never changes at runtime. `ActualHeight` does.

Comment: Great ok thanks for that.  Can it not bind to the images height itself? It shouldn't really matter either way I'm just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way.  First, you need a converter:

```
public class HeightToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var gridHeight = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);

        return gridHeight < 200 ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And here is the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Name="grid">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:HeightToVisibilityConverter x:Key="HeightToVisibilityConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0"
               Content="Some Text" />
        <Image Grid.Row="1"
               Source="zeros.jpg"
               Visibility="{Binding ElementName=grid,
                                    Path=ActualHeight,
                                    Converter={StaticResource HeightToVisibilityConverter}}" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Just for testing purposes, I set it to hide if the grid height was less than 200.  You can change it to whatever to suit your situation. I'm not saying this is the best or only solution, but hopefully it will get you started...

Comment: thanks this does the job, perfectly.   I basically had implemented this but was trying to use the images height rather than the grid, but the image ActualHeight was always 0 so it didn't work.  What's going on here?

Comment: I'm no WPF expert, but the ActualHeight of the image element isn't set until everything is laid out, so it has a value of 0 the first time the Converter is fired.  For some reason, and I have no idea why, the ActualHeight property of the image control doesn't fire the converter when the window is resized, but the converter does when you bind to the grid's ActualHeight.   Hopefully someone with more expertise than me will chime in, because now I'm curious!

Comment: Interesting.  Well at least its functioning how I want it to, so thanks again.