# WPF RowDefinition "collapse" as set height to 0 when Actualheight below threshold

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my application I generate GUI-elements in code and bind them to properties in a list of objects.
Each of these GUI-elements contains a Grid with various other elements like TextEdits (devexpress), small icons and SpinEdits(devexpress).

They are subjective to the window size. If the size gets to small the controls will get squeezed and text is no longer readable and it looks awful.

The first row should always be readable. I achieved this with

```vbnet
newRow1.MinHeight = 30
```

Now I want to "collapse" the other rows depending on their actual size. Per example if they have <30 px height I want to collapse them because their content isn't readable anyway.

If the window is enlarged they should become visible again.

This looks promising but because rows don't have a Visibility property I don't know how to adapt this solution.
[Can I trigger an event in XAML when a control is less than a certain height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42009617/can-i-trigger-an-event-in-xaml-when-a-control-is-less-than-a-certain-height)

This is how I create the Grid in code

```vbnet
Dim NewGridSchalter As New System.Windows.Controls.Grid
Dim newRow1 As New RowDefinition
Dim newRow2 As New RowDefinition
Dim newRow3 As New RowDefinition

newRow1.MinHeight = 30

NewGridSchalter.RowDefinitions.Add(newRow1)
NewGridSchalter.RowDefinitions.Add(newRow2)
NewGridSchalter.RowDefinitions.Add(newRow3)

Dim NewColumnBild As New ColumnDefinition
Dim NewColumnText As New ColumnDefinition
NewGridSchalter.ColumnDefinitions.Add(NewColumnBild)
NewGridSchalter.ColumnDefinitions.Add(NewColumnText)

NewGridSchalter.ShowGridLines = False
NewGridSchalter.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
NewGridSchalter.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch
```

After that the grid is changed and filled with other controls.
If possible I don't want to collapse the controls individually.

It has to be a grid. I tried this with stackpanels or dockpanels but I need the ability to place controls in there where I want them to and how much space they get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

This piece of code can be added to the end of the code in my question. Its important to use the SizeChanged event of the grid and not of a row otherwise it will start to jump around.

```vbnet
AddHandler NewGridSchalter.SizeChanged, Function()
   If NewGridSchalter.ActualHeight < 70 Then
      newRow2.Height = New GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Pixel)
      newRow3.Height = New GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Pixel)
   Else
      newRow2.Height = New GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
      newRow3.Height = New GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
   End If
End Function
```